# VBA Immediate Window not displaying

Tags: vba, immediate-window

Selecting View>Immediate Window or entering CTRL_G no longer has any effect and the Immediae Window Icon haas a red exclamation point - howw to solve this?

Comment: go the bottom drag the window up.  It has been made too small to see.

Comment: The Immediate Window icon always has a red exclamation point: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQjn8.png

Comment: Thanks - solved tthe issue ussing Window>Tile Vertically